# How to bind jquery function to an asp:TextBox?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, input, textbox, bind

I'm trying to use datepicker in a textbox. It worked when I had this textbox:

```
<input type="text" id="Arrival" placeholder="*Arrival" />

$(function () {
    $("#Arrival").datepicker();
});
```

but then I had to change my input boxes to asp:TextBox elements, and now the datepicker isn't working. This is my textbox now:

```
<asp:TextBox id="Arrival" placeholder="*Arrival" runat="server" onchange="activateSendButton()"/>
```

Am I binding it wrong? Do I have to bind it differently now that it's an asp:TextBox instead of an input element?

Note: This specific problem pertains to datepicker, but I was having trouble binding other jquery functions to my asp:TextBox elements as well.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to bind it differently (although that's an option). The easiest thing to do is to change the `ClientIDMode` to `static` on the control, so that the ID on the client matches the ID on the server. You can also do this at the `web.config` level so you don't need to do it for every control.

```
<asp:TextBox id="Arrival" placeholder="*Arrival" runat="server" ClientIdMode="static" onchange="activateSendButton()"/>
```

The other option is to use an inline expression to put the correct ID into the jQuery selector. But I think that's messier.

```
$(function () {
    $("#<%= Arrival.ClientId %>").datepicker();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ClientID` property of the control:

```
$(function () {
    $('#<%= Arrival.ClientID %>');.datepicker();
});
```